# restricting the region of the mapkitview

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit

I am wondering how you would go about restricting the region of a mapkit view so that you cannot scroll outside the region initially set but anywhere within..

i.e. say you want to only show a single island in your app

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of to do this would be to use the following [MKMapViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html) method:

> - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated

When the user changes the region of the mapView, I would check each corner of the region to make sure it is within the restricted regions bounds. If any corner is outside of the restricted region, create a new region for the mapView that fits to the restricted region.